# Flask- How to import db=SQLAlchemy in separate file

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy

I want to add a new table or add data by calling `db`, but i got some problem when i try to import `db`

`db` return like this `<SQLAlchemy engine=None>`

which mean i didnt already doing this `db.init_app(app)`

this is my file struckture

```
Root
run.py
------>server/__init__.py
```

**Config.py**

```
import os


class Config:
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://root:@localhost/flask_py'
    MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.googlemail.com'
    MAIL_PORT = 587
    MAIL_USE_TLS = True
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('EMAIL_USER')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('EMAIL_PASS')
```

**Run.py**

```
from server import server_app, db
app = server_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from server.config import Config

db = SQLAlchemy()


    def server_app(config_class=Config):
        app = Flask(__name__)
        app.config.from_object(Config)
        db.init_app(app)
        from server.users.routes import users
        app.register_blueprint(users)
        return app
```

in my command line using windows i want to import db, i try like this :

```
D:\PYTHON\root>python
from run import db
db.create_all()
```

but when i check is :

```
<SQLAlchemy engine=None>
```

Comment: Did you set `SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI` in your config? Otherwise, how is it supposed to know what database it's using?

Comment: yeahhh its already set, check my update @roganjosh

Answer (score 0):

I have a full working solution here very similar to what you're doing. Check my layout and then look at the create_db.py.

https://github.com/researcher2/stackoverflow_56885380

It appears in your case the "server_app" is not being executed in your interactive shell. Assuming you are running interactive shell in root directory, you would want to do the following:

```
from server import db, create_app

app = server_app()    
with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```

The annoying thing about flask-sqlalchemy as opposed to plain sqlalchemy is the db is coupled to a flask app. The db config comes from the flask config and the initiation is done during db_init or just SqlAlchemy(db) if you want the simpler version for single app setup.

Your models would also need to be setup properly. In my example above I just had them in the create_db script.

This post may help you as well regarding factories and blueprints. I created the above github to answer it.

[Reflecting different databases in Flask factory setup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56885380/reflecting-different-databases-in-flask-factory-setup/56887486#56887486)